# How to send custom referrer to url?

Tags: php, laravel

I need a small PHP script to ping a domain with custom referrer URL

eg: I need a script to ping a website www.abc.com 4 with a custom referrer URL ie. xyz.com

so that the website abc.com would think that the traffic is from xyz.com

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: What's the exact problem here? What keeps you from doing this?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Why are you trying to do this is the real question?

Comment: use a proxy and just ping the proxy server

Comment: currently, I am using <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL='.$link.'"/> to redirct but i need to send custom referrer before redirect to next url.

Answer (score 0):

Ping is diagnostic tool and does not carry referer, if you need change referer from HTTP requests, you can set referer header in request

Example with cUrl:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.example.com/2');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.example.com/1');
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply how to redirect as well as with this code to the second url?

Comment: You cannot redirect with custom referer, browser fills referer automatically and there is no way you can change this from server-side script. You can make script which act as proxy (make request eg. via cUrl  with custom referrer and then serve response to user). Your question saying you want to check some address, not redirect.